# WP Cufon not working in Firefox

Tags: wordpress, firefox, cufon

I am using the plugin WP Cufon on my Wordpress website, however, the font is not displaying in Firefox. Chrome and Safari are working fine. Can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Looking at the source, it is loading everything, just not displaying...

http://gonuttzo.com

Any help would be soooo appreciated! This is driving me batty.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the Cufon FAQ? https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Cufón doesn’t work in Firefox, but works in other browsers

Cause

This issue is almost certainly caused by an empty stylesheet () in your HTML, which causes Cufón’s CSS load detection to fail. This has been happening in recent versions of Firefox only, and seems to occur a lot with purchased WordPress templates. Note that this snippet will cause your browser to load and use your front page as a stylesheet. It’s pretty much the same as href="/". Extra slowness for zero gain.

Solution

Search your HTML for empty stylesheets. Note that the markup on your site may differ from the example, but searching for href="" might save you some trouble. Also, make sure to use the actual HTML (e.g. View Source in your browser) while doing this, if you only go through your template files the issue might be very difficult to spot as the empty href can be masked by, for example, a variable that has an empty value or a function call that returns an empty value.